# How do i do a recalculate algorithm in octave

Tags: matrix, octave

i have to choose a random column in a random matrix , but sometimes the programs pick a random number that is bigger than the size of the matrix.

```
n = 3 + (10-3)*rand(1,1); 
t = round(n); 
x = randi(t,t); 
u = 3 + (10-3)*rand(1,1);
f = round(u);
if f < n & f ~= 0
for k = 1:t
e(k,1) = x(k,f);
end
end
```

So i used a if to solve that problem ,but i dont know how to recalculate a random number when the proposition `f < n & f ~= 0` is false. Please Help

Comment: Can you explain how you create the random number? Is there a reason for not creating a random number that satisfies the proposition right away?

Comment: You obviously know about `randi`, because you use it. `randi` picks a random index, and you should use it to pick your random column index. If you have `n` columns, then `randi(n)` gives you a random column number.

Comment: Also, if `A` is your matrix, then `A(:,i)` copies column number `i`. You don't need a loop for that.

Comment: Yes! i used the random function to create a random number between 3 and 10 and used de round function to get an integer , that i used to create the random size matrix , then i did the same but with another variable to choose a random column.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% this is what you're trying to do, but:

```
t = randi( [3,10], 1 );   % select a random number 't' in the range 3:10
x = randi( t, t );        % create a t-by-t matrix of random values in the range 1:t
r = randi( t );           % select a random number in the range 1:t
c = x(:,r)                % select the rth column from 'x'
```